# Save audio file specific folder on server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been using the following example -> https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/

Which I made a lot of customization on my end , however when I reach the part of upload to server, it doesn't upload anything.

**Upload.php ( custom file )**

```
if (isset($_FILES['audio_data'])) {

    $fileName = "audio";

    if(empty($_SESSION['foldername'])){
        $_SESSION['foldername']  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/".$_SESSION['username'];
    }

    $uploadDirectory = $_SESSION['foldername'].'/'.$fileName;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio_data']["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
        echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
    }

    echo($uploadDirectory);
}
```

The part where it creates a download link, and the upload one ( standard from the above example )

```
function createDownloadLink(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extension)
    var filename = new Date().toISOString();

    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    //save to disk link
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename+".wav"; //download forces the browser to donwload the file using the  filename
    link.innerHTML = "Save to disk";

    //add the new audio element to li
    li.appendChild(au);

    //add the filename to the li
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename+".wav "))

    //add the save to disk link to li
    li.appendChild(link);

    //upload link
    var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload=function(e) {
            if(this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
            }
        };
        var fd=new FormData();
        fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
        xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
        xhr.send(fd);
    })
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
    li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

    //add the li element to the ol
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

The answer on console is   `Server returned: ""`

which is here: Server returned: ",e.target.responseText .

Answer (score 0):

I turned on the errors on the server, and found out it was a error of configuration of the server.

max_upload_size 
max_execution_time
post_max_size